# Add a Scroll after Nth li in a ul

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to show not more than 3 li elements in a ul that can have `N` li elements. If the ul increase by more than 3 elements, I want to put a scroll.

I seacrhed in Google without an easy solution.

It works fine with this code, but I want to make it fixed to the amount of elements.

```
#ul_notas_lesion{
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Do I need something with Javascript?

This is my code:

```
 <div class="x_content">
                    <br />
                    <ul class="list-unstyled timeline">
                        <li>
                            <div class="block">
                                <div class="tags">
                                    <a href="" class="tag">
                                        <span>Entertainment</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="block_content">
                                    <h2 class="title">
                                        <a>Who Needs Sundance When You’ve Got&nbsp;Crowdfunding?</a>
                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="byline">
                                        <span>13 hours ago</span> by <a>Jane Smith</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="excerpt">Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where you met the producers that could fund your project, and if the buyers liked your flick, they’d pay to Fast-forward and… <a>Read&nbsp;More</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="block">
                                <div class="tags">
                                    <a href="" class="tag">
                                        <span>Entertainment</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="block_content">
                                    <h2 class="title">
                                        <a>Who Needs Sundance When You’ve Got&nbsp;Crowdfunding?</a>
                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="byline">
                                        <span>13 hours ago</span> by <a>Jane Smith</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="excerpt">Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where you met the producers that could fund your project, and if the buyers liked your flick, they’d pay to Fast-forward and… <a>Read&nbsp;More</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="block">
                                <div class="tags">
                                    <a href="" class="tag">
                                        <span>Entertainment</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="block_content">
                                    <h2 class="title">
                                        <a>Who Needs Sundance When You’ve Got&nbsp;Crowdfunding?</a>
                                    </h2>
                                    <div class="byline">
                                        <span>13 hours ago</span> by <a>Jane Smith</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="excerpt">Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where you met the producers that could fund your project, and if the buyers liked your flick, they’d pay to Fast-forward and… <a>Read&nbsp;More</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary mt-3 btn-gray btn-block btn-gray" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_Photo_Upload">Agregar Nota</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: i guess i will need javascript/ or put `max-height` to `ul` with `overflow-x`

Comment: But i want to make it with the amount of elements and not with pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JS to do it dynamically

```js
var list = document.querySelector(".list");
var li = document.querySelectorAll(".list li:nth-child(-n+3)");
var height = 0;
li.forEach((x)=> {
  height += x.offsetHeight;
});
list.style.maxHeight = height + "px";
```

```css
div {
  height: 80px;
}
.list{
overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <div>bla bla</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>second</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div> third</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>bla bla</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is the fix i was searching for. I only changed the overflow-x:auto; to overflow-y: scroll;
as i want the scroll for the height only.

Very thanks for your help.

Comment: happy it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

> Do i need something in Javascript?

No, you don't. At least not for a `<ul>` with regular height `<li>` elements.

### Regular Height `<li>` elements

For a `<ul>` with regular height `<li>` elements, it will suffice to use:

- an explicit height for `<li>`
- an explicit `max-height` for `<ul>`
- `overflow-y: auto` on `<ul>`

---

**Working Example:**

```css
ul {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 12px;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: calc(38px * 3);
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

li {
  width: 90px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item One</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item Three</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item Three</li>
  <li>Item Four</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item Three</li>
  <li>Item Four</li>
  <li>Item Five</li>
</ul>
```

---

### Irregular Height `<li>` elements

For a `<ul>` with irregular height `<li>` elements, you can count the elements with javascript and, if there are more than three, you can:

- calculate the height of the first three `<li>` elements to derive a height value
- apply that height value to a **CSS Custom Property** which represents the reference value for the `max-height` of the `<ul>`

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const lists = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');

for (let list of lists) {

  if (list.getElementsByTagName('li').length > 3) {
    
    let listHeight = list.getElementsByTagName('li')[0].offsetHeight;
    listHeight += list.getElementsByTagName('li')[1].offsetHeight;
    listHeight += list.getElementsByTagName('li')[2].offsetHeight;
    listHeight += 'px';
    
    list.style.setProperty('--list-height', listHeight);
  }
}
```

```css
ul {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 12px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-right: 2px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  --list-height: none;
  max-height: var(--list-height);
}

li {
  width: 90px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor</li>
  <li>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</li>
  <li>adipiscing</li>
  <li>elit, sed do</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Lorem</li>
  <li>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</li>
  <li>elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</li>
  <li>ut labore</li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
  <li>consectetur</li>
  <li>adipiscing elit, sed do</li>
  <li>eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</li>
  <li>Ut enim ad minim</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: of, fine, but you do calc(38*3) and in the li is 24+6, i dont see the other 8 pixels....

Comment: It's the height (`24px`) plus the top and bottom padding (`6px` + `6px`) and the top and bottom border (`1px` + `1px`) of each `<li>`. `38px = 1px + 6px + 24px + 6px + 1px`.

Comment: Does this assume the li elements are of a fixed height? Are they, I thought it was required to scroll on the number of li elements (after 3) rather than a height?

Comment: Ok, fine, its a nice fix, and i will try it, but i dont know if it will works, because i dont controll the size of my li, as i am using gentelella alella and i dont see any fixed configuration in the component for the height.

There is any way to capture the element with javascript and add the scroll after the 3th element +1 appear?

Comment: @Garsiv1932 - I've added a second solution above for lists with variable-height items. I saw the solution by לבני מלכה afterwards and they both (pretty much) use the same approach, only I've gone for a **CSS Custom Property** rather than the raw `max-height` property.